# MVC - Why am I getting a "localhost unexpectedly closed the connection" error when I refresh my view?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that sends a value from a dropdown menu to a controller action called LoadDCBReport.  When using the dropdown, everything works fine and the view that I expect is opened.  When I refresh the page however, I get the error "localhost unexpectedly closed the connection".  Why would refreshing the page cause this type of error?

The URL looks something like this: `https://localhost:5001/Reports/Reports/DelinquentCertificateBalances?TaxYears=Company.Areas.Reports.Models.DelinquentCertificateBalances%2BTaxYear&TaxYears=Company.Areas.Reports.Models.DelinquentCertificateBalances`...(continued)

**View/Javascript**

```
$('#savedCriteria').on('change', function () {
    //Ajax form post
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { selectedCriteria : $('#savedCriteria option:selected').text() },
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadDCBReport", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString())',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) {
                window.location.href = data;
            } else {
                window.location.href = data;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadDCBReport(string selectedCriteria)
{
    ReportTaxYearSummary report = new ReportTaxYearSummary(ReportTaxYearSummary.TypeOfReport.DelinquentCertBalance);
    report.GetAvailableSavedCriteria(out List<ReportCriteria> criteria, out Notification not);
    ReportCriteria chosenCriteria = criteria.Where(x => x.CriteriaName == selectedCriteria).FirstOrDefault();
    var reportCriteria = (ReportTaxYearSummaryCriteria)chosenCriteria;

    var convertedReport = new DelinquentCertificateBalances().ConvertObject(reportCriteria);
    TempData.Put("TaxYears", convertedReport.TaxYears);
    TempData.Put("Municipalities", convertedReport.Municipalities);
    TempData.Put("Properties", convertedReport.Properties);

    return Json(Url.Action("DelinquentCertificateBalances", "Reports", convertedReport));
}

public IActionResult DelinquentCertificateBalances(DelinquentCertificateBalances report)
{
    ReportTaxYearSummary dcb = new ReportTaxYearSummary(ReportTaxYearSummary.TypeOfReport.DelinquentCertBalance);
    dcb.GetAvailableSavedCriteria(out List<ReportCriteria> criteria, out Notification not);

    if (report.SelectedCriteria == null)
    {
        var model = new DelinquentCertificateBalances
        {
            TaxYears = DCBGetTaxYears(),
            Municipalities = DCBGetMunicipalities(),
            Properties = DCBGetProperties()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        report.TaxYears = TempData.Get<List<DelinquentCertificateBalances.TaxYear>>("TaxYears");
        report.Municipalities = TempData.Get<List<DelinquentCertificateBalances.Municipality>>("Municipalities");
        report.Properties = TempData.Get<List<DelinquentCertificateBalances.Property>>("Properties");
        report.Criteria = criteria;
        return View(report);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you refresh, does the browser ask you to resubmit the form data? How long do you wait before the connection is closed? Does it happen every time? Is the debugger attached to the web app process?

Comment: @rfmodulator The browser doesn't ask to resubmit the form, and the error happens instantly after refreshing.  It happens every time.  I'm not sure what you mean by the web app process. I can set debug breakpoints and they pause the application at the correct points, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Okay, yeah that's what I mean... what happens if you change this line: `if (report.SelectedCriteria == null)` to this: `if (report == null || report.SelectedCriteria == null)`?

Comment: @rfmodulator I just set a breakpoint on the IActionResult call, and the DelinquentCertificateBalances action never gets called after the refresh.  I'll try to add your code as well, but it never even gets to that point before the error happens.

Comment: Okay... I'm just trying to wrap my head around it. Is there another `DelinquentCertificateBalances` action somewhere?

Comment: @rfmodulator Nope, there is no other action with the same name. Maybe a workaround to this issue count be to remove URL parameters entirely on page refresh and just display the starting page for an empty report.  I'll have to look into how this can be done.

Comment: Yeah, I think so... the URL that you posted wouldn't route to that action, at least not automatically. Writing parameters to `window.location.href` is breaking it your refresh... but I don't know why it's giving you a closed connection instead of a 404. If you want to maintain a refreshable state of Ajax operations you can use an anchor (`#`) instead of parameters (`?`,`&`).

Comment: @rfmodulator do you mean using an anchor for the href attribute of a button? Or another type of anchor? pardon my ignorance, I don't use ajax often.  Is there something similar that can be done for a dropdown selection?

Comment: So if you have a URL like this "https://example.com/#somedata", the server will ignore the "#somedata" part. You can then use JavaScript to parse it, and "refresh" the Ajax parts of your page.